# Macbook display flashing when using Terminal

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, crash, ssh

the macbook I use for work will very occasionally 'blink' or 'flicker' while using external machine connections such as the Terminal or programs that connect to databases (used for work). As a bonus, occasionally, if these connections are left open for too long, my Macbook screen will go white or white/black striped. At this point, the only way to effect this is to manually restart the laptop. Has anyone seen this before and does anyone have any advice on how to solve this or at least begin to diagnose the problem?

This problem has no sounds or other cues associated with it other than the occasional flashing. I've disabled flashing/sounds for errors in the system preferences.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't the same problem as the question linked by user bmike. I have already disabled the audio and visual cues for terminal. This problem also persists regardless of the terminal is on screen or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is the "beep" when the Mac sound is off. This happens if you press the arrow down key at the end of the history queue.

Comment: Hi, do you mind clarifying what you mean by this? the problem does not have any audio cue associated with it regardless of if the volume is muted or not. I've also disabled any audio/visual cues for the terminal in Terminal>Preferences

Comment: Hi, OSX Terminal will beep if a cmd can't be executed. Example: hit backspace at the beginning of a line where no chars can't be deleted, then Terminal will beep if the Mac sound is not muted. If the Mac volume=0 (muted) then the Terminal window will flash (invert the window color shortly)

Comment: But you can disable this in preferences.

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned, I've already disabled this in preferences